# Javascript Date Object incorrect date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I just need another set of eyes on this. I created this code to set a calendar with the current dates on it, it was working fine but today, sat jan 30, the calendar was still showing it start at sat jan 23.

here is the link to my codepen of it:
http://codepen.io/cavascript/pen/MKXrbj

here is the code:

```
  var date = new Date();
  var saturday = date.getDate() - date.getDay() - 1;
  var sunday = date.getDate() - date.getDay() ;
  var monday = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1 ;
  var tuesday = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 2 ;
  var wednesday= date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 3 ;
  var thursday = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 4 ;
  var friday = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 5 ;
  var saturday = (new Date(date.setDate(saturday))).toDateString();
  var sunday = (new Date(date.setDate(sunday))).toDateString();
  var monday = (new Date(date.setDate(monday))).toDateString();
  var tuesday = (new Date(date.setDate(tuesday))).toDateString();
  var wednesday = (new Date(date.setDate(wednesday))).toDateString();
  var thursday = (new Date(date.setDate(thursday))).toDateString();
  var friday = (new Date(date.setDate(friday))).toDateString();
  //add to html row
  $('#dateRow').html('<td colspan="4">Date</td><td colspan="4">'+saturday+'</td><td colspan="4">'+sunday+'</td><td colspan ="4">'+monday+'</td><td colspan="4">'+tuesday+'</td><td colspan="4">'+wednesday+'</td><td colspan="4">'+thursday+'</td><td colspan="4">'+friday+'</td><td>Hours</td><td>Delete</td>');
```

And here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="dateRow">
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Name</td>
        <td colspan="2">Br/lnch</td>
        <td colspan="2">Dinner</td>
        <td colspan="2">Br/lnch</td>
        <td colspan="2">Dinner</td>
        <td colspan="2">Br/lnch</td>
        <td colspan="2">Dinner</td>
        <td colspan="2">Br/lnch</td>
        <td colspan="2">Dinner</td>
        <td colspan="2">Br/lnch</td>
        <td colspan="2">Dinner</td>
        <td colspan="2">Br/lnch</td>
        <td colspan="2">Dinner</td>
        <td colspan="2">Br/lnch</td>
        <td colspan="2">Dinner</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thank you for any input

Comment: Should this table always start one week before the current date?

Comment: this logic doesn't make sense `date.getDate() - date.getDay() - 1` ...do the math ... `30-6-1 = 23`

Comment: No it shouldn't start the week before current date, and you're right the logic doesn't make sense.  It should start at the saturday of that current week.  Sorry guys I was just scatter brained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
date.getDate() - date.getDay() - 1;
```

will return 23 as we are presently on 30/01/2016 - so it does exactly what you asked it to do :)

Check out [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which have a great many helper methods to make Datetime arithmetic much easier.

I guess you don't want the week shown to not *always* be from Saturday 23rd to Fri 29th.

Possible solution: call  getDate() check if result is a Saturday use this as `var saturday` and from there you can deduce Monday - Friday. However, if getDate() is not a Saturday find *previous* saturday and use that.

Also, a useful resource for [calendars](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/useful-calendar-date-picker-scripts-for-web-developers/)

Have a go - if you can't do it then pop me a message and I'll gladly help out.